# group characters within square brackets in grep

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file named `zone-file` with following content:

```
c3-Tx-Msi-US         IN      CNAME   c3-L123-Tx-Msi-US
c3-L123-Tx-Msi-US  IN      A       192.0.2.11
c5-Ny-Msi-US         IN      CNAME   c5-L123-Ny-Msi-US
c5-L123-Ny-Msi-US  IN      A       192.0.2.33
c1-Ny-Gre-SE      IN      CNAME    c1-L123-Ny-Gre-SE
c1-L123-Ny-Gre-SE    IN       A     192.0.2.89
r6-Ms-Msi-UK         IN      CNAME   r6-L123-Ms-Msi-UK
r6-L123-Ms-Msi-UK  IN      A       192.0.2.16
c1-St-Rec-SE      IN      CNAME    c1-L123-St-Rec-SE
c1-L123-St-Rec-SE    IN       A     192.0.2.1
```

I would like to grep out `c3-Tx-Msi-US`, `c5-Ny-Msi-US` and `r6-Ms-Msi-UK`. This means that regular expressions have to include this `Msi` string and output of the grep command should be following:

```
c3-Tx-Msi-US
c5-Ny-Msi-US
r6-Ms-Msi-UK
```

I would like to accomplish this with as loose regular expression as possible which means that search for any character except space or tab up to string `Msi` and then again one or more characters except space or tab. So `grep -Po "^[^ \t]+Msi[^ \t]+" zone-file` would be perfect, but this also includes `c3-L123-Tx-Msi-US`, `c5-L123-Ny-Msi-US` and `r6-L123-Ms-Msi-UK`. Is it possible to group characters inside square brackets? I mean like `grep -Po "^[^ \t'L123']+Msi[^ \t]+" zone-file`? Looks like this is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -oP '\S+Msi\S*(?=.*CNAME)'
```

This uses the Perl-compatible regex engine in GNU grep. It finds a "word" containing the string Msi, where CNAME appears later on in the same line. The `-o` option limits the output to just the matching text.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! However, could you please explain the "\S*(?=.*CNAME)" part. As I understand, you match zero or more whitespace(space, tab, newline) characters with `\S*` and `.*CNAME` should mean zero or more any characters followed by word CNAME, but what does the `(?=)` mean?

Comment: Note that this `\S` is upper case. For perl regex, that means "non-whitespace" characters. So `\S+Msi\S*` is a sequence of non-whitespace chars that contain "Msi". The `(?=.*CNAME)` part is a "look-ahead" assertion meaning "from my current position in the string, does the pattern match what comes next"

Answer (score 1):

For your example, this will do the job:

```
grep CNAME zone-file | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Comment: or with awk: `awk '/CNAME/ {print $1}' zone-file`

Comment: yeah or with sed `sed -E -e 's/(.*)IN[ ]+CNAME.*/\1/' -e '/A/d' zone-file`.  If this is golf, you're winning.

Comment: Thanks for replies! I did not mention in my initial post that this zone-file has other CNAME entries as well. My mistake, sorry. This means that regular expressions have to include this "Msi" string. In addition, I would prefer `grep` if possible.

Comment: @martin, you must put all the requirements up in the question: don't make the people who want to help you read all the comments in all the other answers.